# MySQL trigger insert

Tags: mysql, триггер

Нужно при добавлении записи найти запись в таблице, которая равняется по 2 полям, вставляемой записи и обновить ей поле status на 0.

В чем ошибка?

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_add` BEFORE INSERT  ON `price` FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
UPDATE price
SET price.status_sales = 0
WHERE price.product_variantion_id = new.product_variantion and price.shop_id = new.shop_id and price.status_sales = 1
END;
```

Вылазиет ошибка при добавлении триггера

```
#1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'END' на строке 6
```

Comment: что сейчас происходит? какая ошибка?

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis я добавил запись с таким же id shop и id product, а триггер не сработал, он не обновил поле status на 0, предыдущей записи

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis теперь стало выкидывать ошибку при добавлении
Неизвестный столбец 'inserted.product_variantion' в 'where clause'

Comment: если так: WHERE price.product_variantion_id = new.product_variantion and price.shop_id = new.shop_id and price.status_sales = 1;

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis триггер не срабатывает

Comment: попробуйте использовать after вместо before

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis, а сейчас вообще не добавляет триггер, что за...